# Init const object outside the constructor

Tags: d, dmd

In the following code:

```
class A
{
    void aMethod() { }
    void aConstMethod() const { }
}

class B
{
    const A a; // Not initialized in the constructor, but at a latter time

    void initA()
    {
        a = new A(); // Error: can only initialize const member 'a' inside constructor
    }

    void doStuff()
    {
        //a.aMethod(); shouldn't be allowed to call this here, B can only read from A.
        a.aConstMethod();
    }
}
```

I would like class `B` to only be able to call `const` or `immutable` methods from `A`. However, `B` can only create an instance of `A` after it has already been constructed, so no chance of initializing `A` in the constructor. Can I fix the code above without removing `const` from var `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std.typecons.Rebindable`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#.Rebindable):

```
class A
{
    void aMethod() { }
    void aConstMethod() const { }
}

class B
{
    import std.typecons: Rebindable;

    Rebindable!(const A) a; // Not initialized in the constructor, but at a latter time

    void initA()
    {
        a = new A(); // Error: can only initialize const member 'a' inside constructor
    }

    void doStuff()
    {
        static assert(!__traits(compiles, a.aMethod())); // shouldn't be allowed to call this here, B can only read from A.
        a.aConstMethod();
    }
}
```